# C to MIPS translation with arithmetic operations

Tags: mips

does someone know the translation of this code in c to mips?
I have tried to do it but I don't undertand how to divide or how to do the modulus
d = a – 3 / (b + c + 8);
c = a – 3 % (b + c + 8);

Comment: Depending on the MIPS processor you are using, there is no separate modulus operation, but when you divide, it gives you the integer quotient and integer modulus at the same time in the `hi` & `lo` registers.  Look for the two operand `div` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of these instructions `div` ,`mfhi` ,`mflo`

The hi register contains the remainder of your division operation using the div instruction. In terms of modulo, that's where the modulo value will be saved.

The lo register contains the quotient of your division operation.

```
.data

#Assign your labels values here, I have put zero as placeholder
a: .word 0
b: .word 0
c: .word 0



.text


# a-3
lw $t0 a #load label value a to register $t0
subi $t0 $t0 3 #subtract them by 3

# b+c+8
lw $t1 b
lw $t2 c
add $t2 $t1 $t2
addi $t2 $t2 8
div $t0 $t2 #divide the value at $t0 by $t2
mflo $t0 #quotient value of div operand will be moved to $t0. Here I'll use d as $t0

#this block is for c = a – 3 % (b + c + 8)

# c= a-3
lw $t1 a
subi $t1 $t1 3

# b+c+8
lw $t2 v
lw $t3 c
add $t2 $t2 $t3
addi $t2 $t2 8

#divide the values computed and stored just now in their respective registers

div $t1 $t2
mfhi $t1 #move hi register value to $t1. That's where the modulo value is stored. $t1 now holds c value
```

I would assume you're familiar with other instructions in mips so I do not need to explain the addition and subtraction process here